# Sorting rows using merged cells in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with the excel-vba, I have to sort the rows in ascending order with Column Q with the values of date. but I have encountered an error:

> This operation requires a merged cell of the same size

And also I have this code that is the source of error.

Code:

`Sheet4.Range("Q5:Q" & lastrow).Sort Key1:=Range("A5"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo`

Following is the main page of the column I wanted to sort

[image]

Comment: sorting doesn't like merged cells (well, almost anything doesn't like them). you have to change your sheet layout and have it look like a database . i.e. a sequence of _single_ row records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel can't cope with sorting a range that has a mixture of merged and unmerged cells.  You could sort column Q on its own but not the whole sheet on column Q.

Here is the work around, which you'll need to build into VBA:

For each column with merged cells:
- unmerge the cells
- select the cells
- goto special... blank cells (which will select Q6, Q8, etc
- enter the formula =A5 in all cells
- copy all the cells in the column and copy / paste values

Once you have done that for all columns you can sort

After the sort you can remerge the cells to get back to where you started.

It is a less painful piece of coding than it sounds and will be very effective.